# Get posts under a category with SQL

Tags: categories, taxonomy, terms, sql

How can I retrieve posts under a category with plain SQL with out using WordPress native api's like `get_pages`?

My Wordpress table `wp_terms` contains a term named Restaurants.

I want to list the post comes under this term only.

Is the below query correct?

Am I correct on the `JOIN` parts?

```
SELECT p.ID AS postId, 
    p.post_name,
    p.post_title, 
    p.post_content,
    p.post_excerpt,
    p.post_status,
    p.post_type,
    p.post_author,
    p.guid,
    p.post_modified_gmt
FROM `wp_posts` AS p
LEFT JOIN `wp_term_relationships` AS tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
LEFT JOIN  `wp_term_taxonomy` AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE post_type='place' AND post_status='publish' AND tt.term_id = 11
ORDER BY postId DESC
```

Comment: What's the reason for _"with out using WordPress native APIs"_ ?

Comment: are you not able to get your desired results from wordpress get_posts??

Comment: Guys. I'm developing an api with .NET which pulls data from a WordPress database. And I don't want to use WordPress API or PHP

Comment: Does your query work as expected? If not look over http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/query.php#L1907 for exact query construction and joins.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT p.ID AS postId, 
    p.post_name,
    p.post_title, 
    p.post_content,
    p.post_excerpt,
    p.post_status,
    p.post_type,
    p.post_author,
    p.guid,
    p.post_modified_gmt,
    (SELECT group_concat(t.name SEPARATOR ', ')
   FROM wp_terms t
     LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
     LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
   WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'category' AND p.ID = tr.object_id
  )               AS category
FROM `wp_posts` AS p
LEFT JOIN `wp_term_relationships` AS tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
LEFT JOIN  `wp_term_taxonomy` AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE post_type='place' AND post_status='publish' AND tt.term_id = 11
ORDER BY postId DESC
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?